# Rearrange columns by date

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a dataset with 10 date columns, but some of the dates are not in order. That is, the variable `date1` should have the earliest date, `date2` should have the second earliest date, ..., `date10` should have the latest date. I had previously written two nested for loops and utilized the `nth` function in the `Rfast` package to accomplish this, but I'm getting an error related to the `Rcpp` package and cannot fix it. Is there a more efficient way to do something like this?

Here's a sample of my dataset. As you can see, the 5th observation has dates that aren't in order. `TloBankruptcy4FileDate` has the earliest date, so its value should be given to `TloBankruptcy1FileDate`. The next earliest date is currently in `TloBankruptcy3FileDate`, but it should be assigned to `TloBankruptcy2FileDate`.

I'd like to have a dataset that still has 10 rows and 10 columns, but the values of each variable should be assigned accordingly.

I hope I'm being clear. Thank you!

```
structure(list(TloBankruptcy1FileDate = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 14992, 16764, NA, NA, NA, NA), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy2FileDate = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 14713, 
    10101, NA, NA, NA, NA), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy3FileDate = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 12892, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy4FileDate = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 9282, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy5FileDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy6FileDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy7FileDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy8FileDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy9FileDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date"), 
    TloBankruptcy10FileDate = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), format.sas = "MMDDYY", class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowid) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  mutate(name = str_c("f", row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(rowid)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 11
#>    rowid f1         f2         f3         f4         f5     f6    
#>    <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>     <date> <date>
#>  1     1 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  2     2 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  3     3 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  4     4 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  5     5 1995-06-01 2005-04-19 2010-04-14 2011-01-18 NA     NA    
#>  6     6 1997-08-28 2015-11-25 NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  7     7 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  8     8 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#>  9     9 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#> 10    10 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA     NA    
#> # ... with 4 more variables: f7 <date>, f8 <date>, f9 <date>, f10 <date>
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Is it possible to keep all the rows and all the columns? Your code drops rows that weren't arranged, but I actually need to keep them. Perhaps the only way is to use a nested for loop...

Comment: Your edit works perfectly! Thank you so, so much!

Answer (score 0):

With rowwise operations, `dapply` (from `collapse`) would be faster

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)
dapply(df1, MARGIN = 1, function(x) sort(x, na.last = TRUE)) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), as.Date, origin = '1970-01-01'))
# A tibble: 10 x 10
   TloBankruptcy1Fil… TloBankruptcy2Fi… TloBankruptcy3Fi… TloBankruptcy4Fi… TloBankruptcy5Fi… TloBankruptcy6Fi… TloBankruptcy7Fi… TloBankruptcy8Fi…
 * <date>             <date>            <date>            <date>            <date>            <date>            <date>            <date>           
 1 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 2 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 3 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 4 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 5 1995-06-01         2005-04-19        2010-04-14        2011-01-18        NA                NA                NA                NA               
 6 1997-08-28         2015-11-25        NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 7 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 8 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
 9 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
10 NA                 NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA               
# … with 2 more variables: TloBankruptcy9FileDate <date>, TloBankruptcy10FileDate <date>
```